# Substitute 2 SQL/ORACLE requests by only one request

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

I am trying to get the results of two requests within a single one, these two following requests are functional and each of them are resulting in a table with two columns:

```
SELECT patron.last_name, COUNT(*) AS **pret**
FROM circ_transaction_log INNER JOIN patron ON     circ_transaction_log.patron_id=patron.patron_id
AND **circ_transaction_log.transaction_type<5**
AND patron.college_or_school = 'High School'
GROUP BY patron.last_name;
```

**last_name**     | **pret**
________________
steven grelle   |    552
michelle vins |     122
...

_________________________ **OR** _________________________

```
SELECT patron.last_name, COUNT(*) AS **resa**
FROM circ_transaction_log INNER JOIN patron ON    circ_transaction_log.patron_id=patron.patron_id
AND **circ_transaction_log.transaction_type BETWEEN 5 AND 10**
AND patron.college_or_school = 'High School'
GROUP BY patron.last_name;
```

**last_name**     | **resa**
________________
steven grelle   |    12
michelle vins |     8

...

The result I would like to get is kind of like this :

**last_name**     | **resa** | **pret**
_______________________________
steven grelle   |    552   | 12
 
michelle vins |     122   | 8

...

But I think the difficulty is that I am requesting the same table twice withe count (table CIRC_TRANSACTION_LOG) and whatever I tried was or in error or not working

Thanks in advance for your reply

Regards,
Nickk

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server and Oracle? Are you really using all 3 of those???

Comment: join both of your requests (queries) on last_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're after something like this, then:

```
SELECT   p.last_name, 
         COUNT(case when ctl.transaction_type < 5 then 1 end) AS pret,
         count(case when ctl.transaction_type between 5 and 10 then 1 end) as resa
FROM     circ_transaction_log ctl
         INNER JOIN patron p ON (ctl.patron_id = p.patron_id)
AND      ctl.transaction_type <= 10  -- possibly not required if transaction_type is always <= 10 
AND      p.college_or_school = 'High School'
GROUP BY p.last_name;
```

NB. untested, since you didn't give any sample data for your tables.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is working great, I actually tried to count as you've done with a condition, but I had forgotten the "case" in the synthax... Thanks a Million :)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this method. If the row matches your condition, put 1 in the column, if it doesn't match, put 0. Then when you add up all the values it gives you the number of rows that match. This allows you to create different sums for different conditions.

```
SELECT
    PatronCounts.last_name,
    SUM(PatronCounts.Pret) Pret,
    SUM(PatronCounts.Resa) Resa
FROM
(SELECT 
    patron.last_name, 
    CASE WHEN circ_transaction_log.transaction_type < 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Pret,
    CASE WHEN circ_transaction_log.transaction_type BETWEEN 5 AND 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Resa,
FROM 
    circ_transaction_log 
    INNER JOIN patron ON circ_transaction_log.patron_id=patron.patron_id 
WHERE
    patron.college_or_school = 'High School'
GROUP BY 
    patron.last_name) PatronCounts
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your queries qith a **full outer join** of your result tables **using(last_name)**. This should produce the expected result. Tried to create the query...

```
Select * from
(SELECT patron.last_name, COUNT(*) AS pret
 FROM circ_transaction_log INNER JOIN patron ON circ_transaction_log.patron_id=patron.patron_id
 AND circ_transaction_log.transaction_type<5
 AND patron.college_or_school = 'High School'
 GROUP BY patron.last_name) 
FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT patron.last_name, COUNT(*) AS resa
FROM circ_transaction_log INNER JOIN patron ON circ_transaction_log.patron_id=patron.patron_id
AND circ_transaction_log.transaction_type BETWEEN 5 AND 10
AND patron.college_or_school = 'High School'
GROUP BY patron.last_name) 
USING (last_name)
```

;